# Limit stores - most efficient or easy approach?

Tags: algorithm

Say you have multiple vendors (lets say 5) all selling the same items for different prices.  You must buy item A,B,C, D, E.  Each vendor has item A,B C,D,E so you can easily go through each vendor and find the cheapest version of each item.  However, say you are limited to only shopping from X vendors.  So you must now find the cheapest combinations that make sure you do not use more vendors than allowed.  How does one solve this problem without trying every combination of vendors?

Another way of phrasing an example.

for 5 shops, we are only allowed to use 2 shops to buy 5 items (with each item at a different price in different shops).  How do we save the most money?  Is there a method of solving without trying every combination

Comment: Can you provide the codechef link?

Answer (score -1):

your search is about linear programming ... realy long to explain ^^ : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming

Comment: Please don't answer with only a link. You could add this as a comment when you get enough rep.

Comment: I know it is about linear programming , but I wanted to know in particular if there is any algorithm I can base it off.

Comment: It can't be linear programming; the problem presumably disallows buying fractions of an item, and it's hard to imagine the limited-number-of-vendors constraint as an LP constraint.  It probably could be represented with integer programming, though.

If you do represent it as an integer programming problem, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_cut